# Antennagate: how much of the phone's side should I not touch?

Tags: iphone

*Antennagate* indicates that I should avoid touching that spot of the iPhone where the two metal pieces nearly touch each other - touching here would electrically bridge the two pieces and decrease antenna performance... but it's nearly impossible to hold the phone and **not** touch it there! So here's my question:

**Question:** Should I not touch the two metal parts simultaneously at all, or just not put a finger precisely over the gap? It is okay to touch one centimeter from both sides of the gap? Two centimeters? Half a centimeter?

**If I were to just put a little bit of tape over this side, how long should that piece of tape be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most cases are cheap and will resolve this issue for you completely (and if you have enough money for an iPhone, then you have enough money for a case). I got one and the problem was solved.

**UPDATE:** Based on the comment, if a piece a tape really is necessary, then by the looks of [this product (currently sold out)](http://www.etsy.com/listing/51772143/antenn-aid-for-iphone-4-6-pack) , you are looking at roughly 1 in/2.5 cm in length starting at the mic/speaker hole on the bottom-left. Good luck!

Comment: Yes a case will fix it, and I *have* a case. But with the case, it won't fit in the cradle I also have and it's no fun to pull the phone out of a case to put it in a cradle, so I am really looking for an ultraslimline hack = tape.